# jsp java How to show accented characters correctly

Tags: jsp

I have a spring + hibernate java project that is saving a value data into DB like this: '`Ingl&eacute;s`' where `&eacute`; stands for é.

But when the jsp shows it: `<c:out value="${area.descripcion}"/>`

the page is shown like this: '`Ingl&eacute;s`'.

How Can I make to show the word correctly like this: Inglés ?

the web.xml has configured the encoding:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: View source in browser. You're obviously running the text with `&eacute;` in it through something that's changing the `&` to `&amp;` so that the code becomes `&amp;eacute;` which makes the ampersand show up on screen rather than the whole thing be interpreted as an entity code.

Answer (score 1):

The c:out tag has an escapeXML attribute I had to use to evaluate HTML tags:

```
<c:out value="${area.descripcion}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

With that attribute set to false problem solved!!.